# Foreign key data in admin

Tags: django

Is there any way I can display the total number attending a course in the `list_display` of CourseAdmin?

*admin.py*

```
class Attendee_Inline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Attendee
    extra = 5

class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [Attendee_Inline]
    list_display = ('date','course_name','course','venue','maximum_attendees','get_count')
```

I tried the following:

```
def get_count(self,request):
    this = self.id
    q = Attendee.objects.get(pk=this).count()
    return q
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Have you tried looking at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)?

Answer (score 0):

Write a function inside your Course model which will return the total count of attendees.

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model): 
    ....

    def attendee_count(self):
        q = Attendee.objects.filter(course_id=self.id).count()
        return q

    attendee_count.allow_tags = True
```

Add 'attendee_count' in your list_display of CourseAdmin.

```
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [Attendee_Inline]
    list_display = ('attendee_count',............)
```